# Length limit for a variable name in Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Max name length of variable or method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695951/max-name-length-of-variable-or-method-in-java)

I was reading the java docs and it says “A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits … “ in c++ the variable name length is around 255 characters depending on the compiler, so how is this handled in java does the compiler truncate the variable name after x number of characters, and if this is true what would be x ?

Comment: Why do you expect the compiler to truncate the string if the documentation tells you that strings can be of arbitrary length?

Comment: @KerrekSB I just dont understand how it can be unlimited what if the variable name alone was 15gb

Comment: Maybe the Java compiler comes with an arbitrary-length string class? `BigString` or so... although even the basic string should already be able to grow to a size that's at the order of the addressable machine memory.

Comment: @MikeG: If a variable name requires 15gb to store, then I feel sorry for your keyboard (not to mention your fingers and sanity). I know it's unrelated to the question, but worrying about the limit of the length of a variable name probably means that the name is (just a bit) too long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the class file format spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) (under section 4.11):

> The length of field and method names, field and method descriptors, and other constant string values is limited to 65535 characters by the 16-bit unsigned length item of the CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure (§4.4.7). Note that the limit is on the number of bytes in the encoding and not on the number of encoded characters. UTF-8 encodes some characters using two or three bytes. Thus, strings incorporating multibyte characters are further constrained.

This applies to local variables as well because of the [LocalVariableTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) pointing to CONSTANT_Utf8_info values for the variable names.

Comment: but that is not the flimit or a variable length - the compiler can deal with longer names (tested 70000 with java 11)

Answer (score 2):

No one in their right mind should ever come within miles of the limit.  You reach a point where it defeats the purpose.  You want to choose names that clarify your intent, but that doesn't mean a variable name should rival "Ulysses" in length.  The limit has more to do with good taste and readability.

Comment: Thats not the point i am writing a compiler and i need to know such restrictions

Answer (score -1):

Given that a java.lang.String has a field

```
private final int count;
```

to specify the number of characters in it, the maximum identifier length must be no more than

Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: how are the those things related?