# java get the longest string in enum

Tags: java, enums

I would like to find the longest String within a Java Enum. What is the best way to do this?
I havent been working to much with Enums so any suggestion is welcome. These are my enums

```
 public enum DOMAIN_LANGUAGES {
    ENG, SWE;

    public static List<DOMAIN_LANGUAGES> getDomainLanguages(){
        List<DOMAIN_LANGUAGES> languages = new ArrayList<DOMAIN_LANGUAGES>();
        languages.add(ENG);
        languages.add(SWE);
        return languages;
    }
}

public enum DOMAIN_STATE {
    LIVE,
    PENDING_RENEWAL,
    PENDING_TRANSFER_OUT,
}
```

**EDIT:**

I didnt define this question very well and hence i edit it.
What I whant from my two enums is a function that takes any of the two kind of enums i have defined as and finds the longest literal. So in the DOMAIN_STATE that would be "PENDING_TRANSFER_OUT". I hope this makes things a bit easier to understand.

**EDIT 2**

So now i'v gotten som help that has been great, but im not sure why this code will not work. It complains when i try to use the enumList.values()? This is the reason i couldnt find a solution in the first place, what am i missing? =)

```
    public String CalculateDropdownListWidth(Enum enumList){
        int chars = 0;
        for(Enum e : enumList.values()){
            //do stuff
        }
}
```

**FINAL:**

So now i knwo why this didnt work. I hade to loop over a EnumSet instead of a Enum. Since the Enum is only one in the "set" if im not totally misstaken.
So this is my solution. Thanks all for helping out!

```
public String CalculateDropdownListWidth(EnumSet enumList){
    int chars = 0;
    for(Object e : enumList){
        if(e.toString().length() > chars){
            chars = e.toString().length();
        }
    }

    //Pixelmodifier
    Double oneChar = 1.35;

    Double result = oneChar * chars;

    return String.valueOf(result) + "px";
}
```

Thx for any help!

/Marthin

Comment: Don't need the `getDomainLanguages`. There's a method `values()` defined for every `enum` which returns an array of values.

Comment: I don't see any Strings.  Do you mean the longest enum literal, like `PENDING_TRANSFER_OUT` in your second enum?

Comment: I am confused, there are not strings in the above example and what does DOMAIN_STATE have to do with anything?

Comment: @Jonathon Yes the literal is what i whant find the length of, my bad!

Comment: Has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length/426008#426008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 String longestYet= "";
 for (Enum<?> value :OfferType.values()){
     if (longestYet.length()< value.name().length()) {
        longestYet= value.name();   
     }                
 }
 longest = longestYet;
```

If you need this value very often for a specific enum, then you can add it to the enum itselve, and set the value in a static initialialzer.

```
public static enum MyType {

    NORMAL,
    OTHER;

   public static final String longest; 
   static{
        String longestYet= "";
        for (Enum<?> value :MyType.values()){
           if (longestYet.length()< value.name().length()) {
            longestYet= value.name();   
           }                
        }
        longest = longestYet;
    }        
}
```

*or even better, put the static initializer method, in a Util function that can be reused in several Enums.*

Comment: It is clear in the question if what is wanted is the enum literal or it's length, though.

Comment: This puts a smile on my face. :)

Comment: Thank you, this has helped alot but for some reason i still cant get it working. Please check my last edit.

Comment: @Ralph: I have, it didnt work, I think there might be some problem with the enumList i send in?  CalculateDropDownList(Enum<?> enumList)

Comment: @Marthin: What is the exact problem: exact source code and exact exception/compiler error?

Comment: @Found the problem, need to use EnumSet and loop over objects. Thx for the help! See finaledit for my final code =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `YourEnum.values()` then iterate through all and get the length of the string returned by `name()`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over DOMAIN_LANGUAGES.values and find the longest name.