# In Common Lisp, is there a defined maximum length for a symbol's name?

Tags: common-lisp, language-lawyer, symbols, identifier

I wasn't able to find this information in the [Hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/index.htm) or Common Lisp: The Language (second edition). Implementation-dependent constants like `LAMBDA-PARAMETERS-LIMIT` and `CALL-ARGUMENT-LIMIT`, but not something like `SYMBOL-NAME-LENGTH-LIMIT` or perhaps `PRINTABLE-SYMBOL-NAME-MAX-LENGTH`.

The standard symbols with the longest names are `UPDATE-INSTANCE-FOR-DIFFERENT-CLASS` and `UPDATE-INSTANCE-FOR-REDEFINED-CLASS`, both 35 characters long, so I suppose that 35 could be taken as a maximum. I don't expect to ever name a symbol something longer than that, but it could matter some day.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/426120/3931349 ??

Comment: @rsm thanks. so the standard minimum is 1024 characters; if you'd like to make that into an answer, go ahead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Common Lisp the names of symbols are strings, strings are vectors (one-dimensional arrays) and thus the length of strings is limited by `array-dimension-limit`.

According to CL HyperSpec http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_ar_dim.htm#array-dimension-limit `array-dimension-limit` is:

> A positive fixnum, the exact magnitude of which is implementation-dependent, but which is not less than 1024.

Practically, SBCL reports

```
* array-dimension-limit
4611686018427387901
```

so it's not really a limit.

Comment: Side note: CLtL2 is not really spec. It's a language description of a version of Common Lisp before it was specified as ANSI Common Lisp. Thus there are differences to the actual ANSI CL spec. A HTML rendering of something which has basically the same contents as the spec is the HyperSpec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm

Comment: @RainerJoswig Oh, I didn't knew that, thanks! I changed CLtL2 part to HyperSpec.